# au run - No js files included in the app-bundle

Tags: node.js, npm, aurelia

I've just upgraded my aurelia application to the latest and now find that it fails at run time - no errors reporting during the build. Fails with

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__useDefault' of undefined
at ensureOriginOnExports (vendor-bundle.js:14252)
```

This is because it can't find the "app" class in the app-bundle. Upon looking at the app-bundle - there is no application js classes/code included - only the html & css is present (the app-bundle size is reduced from 225KB to 125KB so is quite obvious when you know what to look at). aurelia-cli version 0.24.

Prior to the update - all was fine.

However if I do `au new` and then `au run` - it works as expected. The difference is the tracing succeeds - lists app/environment/main etc where as for my project it only lists app & nav-bar (needs to also list environment/main etc). This is using typescript 2.1.5.

I have updated the aurelia.json file to be compatible with cli >= 0.23 - in fact is almost exactly the same as the one produced by `au new`.
The vendor-bundle does contain the js code as expected (size is also about the same).

Any ideas?
Thanks
Windows 10/Node v6.9.4/npm v4.1.1

Comment: this shouldn't make any difference, but try to update the global version of cli, by running `npm install aurelia-cli -g`. Also, delete the scripts folder and run `au run` again.

Comment: Had already done that. No difference. Even uninstalled the cli and went back to 0.18 - also no difference which suggests the issue is with a dependency of the cli. If I copy in a old version of the projects `node_modules` then the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading between cli versions the recommended way is to scaffold new project with au new with same choices and then copy tasks over to yours.. and bump the depenencies